# Adding a ng-required validator dynamically on a form validator AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have a form with AngularJS validation.
The problem is that I add validators in a elements dynamically:

```
if (constraint.NotNull){
    elem.attr("ng-required","true");
}
```

The NgModelController for this element always evaluate "form.$valid = true", even with empty value.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the attribute dynamically. If you read carefully enough on AngularJS API reference for ngRequired, you will learn that the value for ngRequired can be binded. The example there is the best.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

In your case create

`$scope.isRequired = {
   field1: true,
   field2: false,
   ...
}`

You can change this dynamically and AngularJS will reflect that.

Comment: tank u, your solution save my life. But i'm not understand yet, why my solution not works.

Comment: It didn't work because you would have to re-render the view or do a digest cycle to reflect it in the DOM.

Comment: Petr, help me please. How make a re-render view or do a digest cycle? I tried "$compile(content.contents())(scope));", but not work. The form Angular is always invalid, same valid.

Comment: Try `$scope.apply()`.